# PROLOG how to "connect" similar objects

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

Hey im new to prolog and was wondering:

Let's say i have this code:

```
component(a,b).  
component(a,c).   
component(a,d).  
component(b,e).  
component(b,f).
```

and i want to create an argument
 `consistsof(X,Y):- component(X,Y); component(Y,Z).`

that gives me:

Y= b,c,d,e,f

so i want to get the result of "a" plus the result of the ones "a" is connected with (b,e) and (b,f). Im sorry if im not very specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a transitive closure

```
part_of(Object, Part) :-
    component(Object, C), (Part = C ; part_of(C, Part)).
```

and [setof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3)/3

```
?- setof(C, part_of(a,C), L).
L = [b, c, d, e, f].
```

note this requires an acyclic graph, or will loop forever